# iOS: 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete row 1 from section 4, but there are only 3 sections before the update'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsindexpath

I have created a drop down table view cell, but when inserting and deleting a row into section app crashes with following error,

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete row 1 from section 4, but there are only 3 sections before the update'
```

I am reloading data of tableview with two different arrays on button click.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if (tagforTable==1)
        return [updateDataArray count];
    else
        return [offersDataArray count];
}
- (void)didSelectCellRowFirstDo:(BOOL)firstDoInsert nextDo:(BOOL)nextDoInsert
{
    [self.notificationTable beginUpdates];

    int section;
    self.isOpen = firstDoInsert;

    Cell1 *cell = (Cell1 *)[self.notificationTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.selectIndex];
    [cell changeArrowWithUp:firstDoInsert];


    section = self.selectIndex.section;

    dbObj=[[DatabaseHelper alloc]init];
    if (tagforTable==1)
    {
        [dbObj updateTagUpdate:section];
    }
    else if(tagforTable==2)
    {
        [dbObj updateTagOffers:section];
    }
    [upCount removeAllObjects];
    [ofCount removeAllObjects];
    upCount=[dbObj SelectTagForUpdate];
    ofCount=[dbObj SelectTagForOffers];
    notificationBtn.badgeValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[upCount count]+[ofCount count]];
    notificationBtn.badgeBGColor = [UIColor redColor];


    NSMutableArray* rowToInsert = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSIndexPath* indexPathToInsert = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:section];
    [rowToInsert addObject:indexPathToInsert];

    if (firstDoInsert)
    {   [self.notificationTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:rowToInsert withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.notificationTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:rowToInsert withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    }

    [rowToInsert release];

    if (nextDoInsert) {
        self.isOpen = YES;
        self.selectIndex = [self.notificationTable indexPathForSelectedRow];
        [self didSelectCellRowFirstDo:YES nextDo:NO];
    }
    if (self.isOpen) [self.notificationTable scrollToNearestSelectedRowAtScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    [self.notificationTable endUpdates];

}
```

where I am going wrong ? Help !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tableview update 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14931152/tableview-update-nsinternalinconsistencyexception-reason-invalid-update-in)

Comment: Tirth: How u can say that ? I mean please explain.

Comment: Yup it is. This is problem of data-source management. Check your data each line by line and compare with main data-source, your problem will solved.

Comment: I have two arrays with 5 and 3 elements respectively. When I click on 5th element of 1st array and then by loading second array as I click on 3rd element, app crashes.

Comment: Okey, then where are you remove 5th element from main datasource?? I mean 5 element array??? You applying changes on tableview but not seem to on main datasource array.

Comment: Where you update the arrays updateDataArray,offersDataArray  after insert or delete?

Comment: I dnt delete element from array, I just use them to display same like a drop down table view cell. As a row is added to section on click as a dropdown.

Comment: You must update main table data source before attempting updation on table.If you delete row then you must delete before array element, if you add element then you must add before element in array.

Comment: Ok mate. Let me try your suggestions. :)

Comment: [yourTable reloadData] maybe help

Comment: i don't think so it will solved after just reloading data. If you reload data then your table reload and as it is without updation, becoz that reason is you not updating main datasource. Table view beginUpdated and endUpdates method updating only given bunch of rows not whole tableview reloading.

Comment: Tirth: what should I do then to update whole table ?